# Multiple answers and unanswerable questions

Tags: discussion, answers

I have a concern regarding the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site: It seems to me that when a question is posted for code review that there really can be multiple correct answers.

In fact, the FAQ states:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

But as I read through many of the questions, it seems that many of them are "un-answerable".  So my concern here is how useful it is. Perhaps a different format for accepting the correct answers would help, such as allowing the user to pick the top 3 useful suggestions.

Or am I missing some key information here?

Comment: Related: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54/which-answer-to-accept/73#73. You do not *have* to accept an answer, and there are many ways of recognizing good answers other than accepting.

Answer (score 10):

> there is really can be multiple correct answers

Multiple correct answers is not really a problem; there is always "more than one way to do it".

The only time it is a problem is when the # of answers is infinitely large and always growing. in practice this has not been a problem on Code Review, probably because each code snippet is quite specific.